# Base de datos + Servidor compartido + Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, servidor

Muy buenas gente,

Tengo la siguiente duda; Dispongo de un proyecto en Laravel ( v5.6 con php v7.2 ) conectado con una base de datos en local y quiero reconectar-la con la base de datos de un servidor compartido ( CDMON ).

Por lo que entiendo, tengo que modificar los datos de los archivos .env y /config/database.php de mi proyecto. Pero una vez hecho esto, me salta el error
correspondiente:

[image: ErrorDB]

Es como si esta me siguiese apuntando a la base de datos que tenia antes.

Mi archivo **.env**:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.xxx.x.xxx
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=reporting
DB_USERNAME=mywel6902
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

Mi archivo "**/config/database.php**":

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.xxx.x.xxx'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'reporting'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'mywel6902'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxx'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

¿Como le digo que me apunte a la nueva base de datos? ¿Debo limpiar la caché del servidor?

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: subistes tu proyecto ya al servidor con los cambios? porque con ese error yo entiendo que lo subistes pero no cambiastes nada,  yo te sugiero que mires los permisos de tu bd del servidor y ver cuales son el usuario y password de tu bd en tu servidor

Comment: Si, subí mi proyecto con FTP al servidor y luego que me saltó este error, modifiqué los archivos para que me apuntase a la nueva base de datos. Pero nada, me sale el mismo error.

Comment: A lo mejor tengo que borrar la caché del servidor para que me "guarde" los cambios.

Comment: intenta eso  y si te da error podrias agregar el log de tu servidor(solo la parte donde mysql se esta ejecutando) asi podria ayudarte

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a hablar con los de CDMON para ver si me pueden borrar la caché y pasarme el log, ya te diré como ha ido. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si en el servidor no dispones de línea de comandos, justo antes de subir los archivos utiliza los siguientes comandos desde la carpeta del proyecto `php artisan config:clear` y `php artisan cache:clear`. Inmediatamente después sube el proyecto y edita los archivos para que te tome la configuración en el archivo `.env`

Comment: @Xerif buena respuesta

Comment: Ya está, se ve que los archivos estaban correctamente, solo que no se porqué no se subían al servidor. Muchas gracias a todos por responder.